# Visual Studio: Unable to add to the Web site... Unable to add file... Access is denied Error 550

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, publish

I am trying to publish my project from my development machine to the staging environment. I would right click the project in visual studio and click publish. Most of the files would publish just fine, but a few were giving me problems. In the output log, there were multiple error messages, all stating:

Unable to add ‘XXX.ext’ to the Web site. Unable to add file ‘XXX.ext’. Access is denied (550)

I'm following [this](http://www.victorfeinman.com/2010/09/vs2008-publish-error-access-is-denied/) : But I don't find the "Read-only" attribute checkbox...

So have you any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe some files are being used on the staging enviroment. try stopping iis and publishing the files.

Comment: the 'read-only' attribute checkbox is in the standard properties dialog which opens on any file/folder in windows(on your server, not the dev machine)

Answer (score 32):

I just solved this problem on my own system. It was a permissions issue. What I had to do was grant "write" rights to myself on the IIS directory (in my case wwwroot). I retried the publish from Visual Studio and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah spot on. Just go to the folder in question -> right click -> properties -> make sure your user has the write permission checked. That worked for me. Thanks for this made my life a bit easier.

Answer (score 21):

Open visual studio in administrator mode. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

**If you only get this for select files**:

1. Go to the Server Published file folder
2. Select the problem Files
3. Properties
4. **Uncheck Read-Only**

Apparently this can occur when **Source Control non-checked out files are read only, and then someone just copies specific files**.

*(I tried other people's suggestions: giving myself write access to wwwroot, running VS as admin, but for me it was the read-only that did the trick.)*

Comment: Little secret, if you don't want a file to deploy, you can also similarly purposefully make the file on the server read-only.  Why would you want to?  Well, an example might be if you're pre-compiling your site and yet it causes some problems with say SSRS reports or other files.

Comment: This was it for me.  The message is a little misleading because it doesn't indicate if the issue is on your local machine or to where you are publishing.  Going to the folder on the server I was publishing to and unchecking read-only worked for me.  I think this happens because I publish from TFS which sets the files to read-only.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already published your solution and now it is not publishing, then run the Visual Studio on Administration mode and then publish it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I already tried to uncheck the 'Read-only' in the problem folder and files but still doesn't work. I already run the VS as administrator. What I did is just simply restart the visual studio and publish the project again, and it solves the problem.

Comment: Seems silly but this worked.  (mine is a WPF app) What I observed is that VS was creating a folder for resource file and setting it to read-only Then tried to copy the file.  Restarting the App made a difference.  Thank you Satria.

Answer (score 1):

We had to add full path to publish location.  So whereas the publish location used to be:

\webtest1\W_Apps

We did this:

\webtest1\D$\webdata\Intranet\Depts\SO\W_Apps

and then we didn't have the error message

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to **recycle the Application Pool for the website in IIS**.  I had this problem (access denied) for a few of the folders in the publish directory and none of the above solutions worked for me.  After I recycled the app pool, I was able to publish with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

it has permission problem of your web server
You must go to physical address of your website and share in with user of ftp account that you've create before and and your problem solve

Answer (score 0):

Are you **LOCAL administrator** to your own PC? If not, that could be the problem and it's how I solved the issue at work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. I solved this by giving Full control under 'Security' tab for Users for the deployment folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I have followed the below steps to fix the issue:

First of all you have to identify that which account you are accessing visual studio. In my case, I have used my organization account.

1. Go to your deployment which you set as "Target Location" in publish
   profile
2. Right click the deployment folder
3. Go to Security tab
4. In the list of users, identify the account using which you are
   accessing Visual Studio ( in my case organization account)
5. Grant full permission by checking the check box "Full control" and click
   "Apply"